# Integration of Google Cloud Sql Server with Google Apps Script

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have problems to connect sql server on google cloud to google apps script, have tried many options do url connection like:

```
Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://MYINSTANCE","sqlserver", "*****");
```

but is not connecting

> Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection
>   string.

Do you can help me to solve this problem to connect Sql Server to Google Apps Script?

Information about google cloud Sql Server:

DB Type: SQL Server 2017 Standard
Location: southamerica-east1-b

Using sql server management studio, I have tested and connected successfully, with this information

Comment: You say you're connecting to SQL Server, but using a `mysql://` URI in the connection string. I don't think that's correct. I've edited your post to remove your instance's name & IP information - that's not something you want to broadcast on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you alroc for help me, I'm tried to used 
jdbc:google:sqlserver and 
jdbc::sqlserver 
but don't work too.

Comment: Have you tried this in a simple Java program?  I would imagine you want something like mssql:// for your URL.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-ver15 See also: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Comment: Thank you @Frank for helping me, I will try this too, but I think is a bug in google apps script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not yet implemented to connect to the GoogleSQL SQL Server through Apps Script.

There is already a [feature request made in Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/145468422), you actually seem to be the person that created the Issue so I will leave the answer for visibility if someone faces the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for you repply Raserhin!
I entered a new ticket with this problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145468422
I think is a problem in the google apps script

Comment: Google Cloud SQL for SQL Server is still in beta so its going to be a while before its available via Apps Script's JDBC connector.